# Why only the random.random() function generates different numbers every time even several million runs. The other random functions do give same o/p

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

This is the code I used

```
import random as r    

count =  0    
num1 = 0    
num2 = 1
```

We have used this number because random gives 15 digit decimal output and with that
437893890381000000 combinations are possible

```
while num1 != num2 or count <= 437893890381000000:     

    num1 = r.random()
    num2 = r.random()

    count+=1
    print(count,' num1= ',num1,' num2= ',num2)

print('after ',count,' times, the code generated same numbers as: ',num1,' ',num2)
```

The code ran for several million times still got no same output.

Comment: `and` instead of `or`?

Comment: if we used `and` instead of `or` the loop will go up to the number even if `num1 = num2` so i have used `or`

Comment: No, that what it does now.

Comment: `and` will give `True` only if both conditions are satisfied whereas `or` will give `True` when either condition is true.

Comment: @KlausD. is saying your code will try to run the while loop for at least 437893890381000000 iterations, this is probably not what you want

Comment: @SamMason But try to think it this way:-  the code uses `or` and before 437893890381000000 iterations `num1` becomes equal to `num2` then the `while` loop will break whereas if I used `and` the code will definitely run for 437893890381000000 iterations even if `num1 = num2`.

Comment: but that's not how Python "thinks about it".  if you actually want a real Python implementation to stop the loop the first time `num1 != num2` you'll need an `and` there.  Python has well defined semantics here and it's following them, it doesn't care how you're thinking it "should" work

Comment: note that you should expect matching doubles around 9e15 iterations (95%CI 2.3e14 to 3.3e16) so you need to run for significantly longer than "several million times" (i.e. a thousand million times as long as you have)

Comment: @SamMason Ahh... actually I am new to python and i still don't got this concept. Can you suggest me some resources to better understand this thing or *if you don't mind* can you explain this in a bit more detail. :)

Comment: try replacing your calls to `random()` with ones to `input()` and then you'd get control over when things are equal.  also just `print(num1 != num2 or count <= 437893890381000000)` in the loop to see when it goes `False`.  running the code in a debugger might help as well